# Using jQuery with ajax to target a single instance of a class applied to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an HTML table where each row contains information about a bookmark previously saved by the user. When the user clicks the span in the first table cell, I'm using jQuery to confirm the action, change the styling of the span, and then execute a delete query on the server via ajax. Everything works as expected -- targeting only the span that was clicked -- except the ajax part. I only want to delete the current row, but the way the code is written it's deleting every row.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>                            
            <div class="entry-bookmark">
            <span class="bookmark-icon entry enabled" data="8"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/title1/">Title 1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>                            
            <div class="entry-bookmark">
            <span class="bookmark-icon entry enabled" data="9"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/title2/">Title 2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>                   
</table>
```

And the jQuery like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bookmark-icon.entry.enabled", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this bookmark?");
    if (r == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).removeClass("enabled");
    $(this).addClass("disabled");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).fadeIn(1500);
    var entryID = $(this).attr("data");
    var bookmarkData = {
        entryID: entryID,
        value: 0
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/bookmark/',
        type: 'post',
        data: bookmarkData
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we see your server-side code? I'm not seeing any errors in the jQuery at a glance.